# I can't see image's title while a dropdown stays open

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I would like to ask a question about whether a behavior might be reported as a bug or not

Let's say I have a dropdown and several images to its right. Each image had a title so if the mouse pointer is over any of them I can see the title...

But if I click the dropdown and I move the mouse over the images, I cant see any title in several browsers:

- Ubuntu + Chrome **Fail**
- Windows 7 + IE >= 9  **Fail**
- Windows 7 + FF OK
- Windows 7 + Chrome Ok
- Ubuntu + FF Ok

I attached a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pf1mbvy3/1/

```
<select title="dropdown title" aria-invalid="false"><option value="" class="ng-binding ng-hide" aria-hidden="true">Select...</option><option value="1">option 1</option><option value="2" selected="selected">option 2</option></select>

<img src="http://venturesafrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/free-web-traffic.jpg" class="img-right" title="image title" />
```

Its a bug or not?

Could you give me any link or some information about that?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's related to the way in which each browser interprets the select when open, and the hover event. Possibly in browsers that it gives you fault, it's because the show select menu options, the menu itself occupies the entire focus of the page. Try some hover effects on images, such as putting a colored border hovering above, to see if it also fails in such cases.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Probably has to do with the way different engines handle element focus. Can't find any info on this. Seems like a small enough problem to have been overlooked...